# invertible ring r -1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

False 
the ring of integers: R=Z. The only invertible elements in this ring are 1 and −1. To make this clear, suppose a∈Z is invertible. then there is some a^-1∈Z such that aa^-1=a^-1a=1. But aa^-1=1 implies that a^-1=(1/a)∈Q, clearly a^-1 belongs to Z if and only if a=1 or −1

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas are correct, but I believe (IMHO) that the way of writing is a little bit off.

If you want to prove something is wrong, simply show a counter-example.

For example : "In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, only $1$ and $-1$ are invertible. If we take $r = 3$, $r-1 = 2$, which is not invertible. Hence, the statement is wrong."